# NSUserNotification Custom Sound (OS X, Sandboxed App)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I'd like to use a custom sound for Notification Center, but cannot find much documentation on this. I know how to assign a sound to a notification, and I know how to copy new sound files to ~/Library/Sounds then use these new sounds. My app is sandboxed so I of course have to ask the user to confirm they want to install the new sounds, but am concerned about App Store rejection based on this App Store rule:

**2.15**
Apps must be self-contained, single application installation bundles, and cannot install code or resources in shared locations

Anyways, is it possible to use a custom sound with a NSUserNotification without copying a resource to ~/Library/Sounds ?

Seems like there is [documentation for this on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6), but nothing for OS X.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NSNotification` and `NSNotificationCenter` have nothing to do with the Notification Center in the OS X UI (the thing which slides in from the right). And they have nothing to do with sounds. You presumably are talking about `NSUserNotification` and `NSUserNotificationCenter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by the declaration of the `soundName` property of the `NSUserNotification` class in the headers reads (emphasis added):

> The name of the sound file **in the resources of the application bundle** to play when the notification is delivered. NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName can be used to play the default Notification Center sound. A value of 'nil' means no sound.

So, you can simply ship a sound file in your app bundle's resources and use its name for the user notification's `soundName`. Almost certainly, this is similar to the [`+[NSSound soundNamed:]` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSSound/soundNamed:), so you should pass the file name minus the file extension.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working. It should be the answer, however. I can use NSSound soundNamed: to play the sound but when trying to use the same sound on the NSUserNotification, nothing plays. I'm assuming this is a bug in OS X. The only way I can get the notification sound to change is if the custom sounds are copied into ~/Library/Sounds.

Comment: For now, I am just going to play the custom sound manually using something like the following: `[[NSSound soundNamed:[self.prefsNotifSoundButton titleOfSelectedItem]] play];`